# Why is the listview empty and not showing the data?

Tags: android-listview

Why is the listview empty and not showing the data?

```
Database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
ref = Database.getReference().child(Let).child(Gen);

arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
ListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

//

ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
        //arrayList.clear();
        String value = snapshot.getValue(Name.class).getName();
        arrayList.add(value);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, @Nullable String previousChildName) {
           arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        }
    });

arrayList.clear();
arrayAdapter.clear();

    }

    }
```

Comment: Tidied the code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
String value = snapshot.getValue(Name.class).getName();
```

with

```
 String value=String.valueOf(snapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class));
```